# Read Access Denied For Visual Force Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller, permissions

I'm trying to display a table of object permissions. However, when I try to connect my controller with my `Visualforce Page`, I'm am receiving the error:

> Read access denied for ObjectPermissions.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customobjectperm}" var="objectPer"  headerClass="permTable">
                   <apex:column value="{!objectPer.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**Apex**

```
public List<String> customobjectperm{get;set;}

customobjectperm =  [SELECT Label, Profile.Name,  ProfileId, 
                      (SELECT SobjectType, PermissionsEdit  
                          FROM ObjectPerms 
                          WHERE SObjectType  = 'qbdialer__DialerQuery__c'),
                      (SELECT SobjectType, Field, PermissionsRead 
                          FROM FieldPerms 
                          WHERE SObjectType  = 'qbdialer__DialerQuery__c')
                     FROM PermissionSet  WHERE ProfileId  = :userId  LIMIT 1];
```

Has anyone had this problem or know whats going on here?

Comment: <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customobjectperm}" var="objectPer"  headerClass="permTable">
                   <apex:column value="{!objectPer.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

Comment: why would the last line of the where clause try and match `profileId` to apex variable `userId`?